# How can we analyse the match score of openBR

Tags: openbr

How to analyse the score in `csv` file such as `23.9256`

```
br -algorithm FaceRecognition -compare set.gal img.jpg score.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A match score of 0 corresponds to the average impostor match score, and a match score of 1 corresponds to the average genuine match score (where the averages were computed from the training set). Thus a match score of 23.9268 is "very high".

[Reference](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openbr-dev/W3TTYZ885kc)