# What does the score actually mean in openbr FaceRecognition

Tags: opencv, face-recognition, biometrics, openbr

Command:

```
br -algorithm FaceRecognition -compare 2017-01-26-100725.jpg 2017-01-26-105640.jpg
```

Output:

```
Set algorithm to FaceRecognition
Loading /usr/local/share/openbr/models/algorithms/FaceRecognition
Comparing 2017-01-26-100725.jpg and 2017-01-26-105640.jpg
Enrolling 2017-01-26-100725.jpg to 2017-01-26-100725IaPSB4.mem
100.00%  ELAPSED=00:00:00  REMAINING=00:00:00  COUNT=1
100.00%  ELAPSED=00:00:00  REMAINING=00:00:00  COUNT=1
4.14855
```

Command:

```
br -algorithm FaceRecognition -compare 2017-01-26-100725.jpg 2017-01-26-100725.jpg
```

Output:

```
Set algorithm to FaceRecognition
Loading /usr/local/share/openbr/models/algorithms/FaceRecognition
Comparing 2017-01-26-100725.jpg and 2017-01-26-100725.jpg
Enrolling 2017-01-26-100725.jpg to 2017-01-26-100725IaPSB4.mem
100.00%  ELAPSED=00:00:00  REMAINING=00:00:00  COUNT=1
100.00%  ELAPSED=00:00:00  REMAINING=00:00:00  COUNT=1
23.9268
```

Note that the last command is comparing two identical images. What does the last number mean? I'm guessing it's the score? If so then relative to what?

In all of the documentation on the openbr site there is no mention of the output given by the FaceRecognition command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can analyse match score of openBR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34630421/how-can-analyse-match-score-of-openbr)